# Unable to start Apache server [apache-2.2.29]

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have installed Apache as root and provisioned port `7773` in my `httpd.conf` file.

When I try to start `apachectl` then I get the error below:

`[root@iam-dev bin]# ./apachectl -k start`
`httpd: Syntax error on line 420 of /home/app/apache-2.2.29/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 9 of /home/app/apache-2.2.29/conf/webgate.conf: Cannot load /home/app/Middleware/Apache22_WebgateR2PS2_Home/webgate/apache/lib/webgate.so into server: /home/app/Middleware/Apache22_WebgateR2PS2_Home/webgate/apache/lib/webgate.so: undefined symbol: nzos_GetSSLSessionID`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable to point /home/app/Middleware/Apache22_WebgateR2PS2_Home/webgate/apache/lib and the Apache Home lib dir. Like,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/app/Middleware/Apache22_WebgateR2PS2_Home/webgate/apache/lib:<Apache Instal Dir>/lib
```

Also, you can find out the libs that are not getting resolved using following command.

```
ldd home/app/Middleware/Apache22_WebgateR2PS2_Home/webgate/apache/lib/webgate.so
```

HTH,
Anil